# Last occurrence of a word and trailing

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match the last occurrence of a word (excluded) in a sentence with the remaining words.

Example
Looking for the word "potato, ", expecting to select what's in bold:

> potato, orange, potato, **plum, pear, etc.**

Regex I put together is something like this however not working fully

```
(potato:(?!.*potato)).*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for 1 or more groups of "anything followed by potato", without capturing them, then capture the rest of the string:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?:.*potato)+(.*)')
m = regex.match('potato, orange, potato, plum, pear, etc.')
m.groups(1)[0]

# ', plum, pear, etc.'
```

And as a plus, you don't have to make *potato* appear twice in the regex.

Comment: Admit that I am still not clear on how this works, but... it works! Thank you vm!!

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
potato(?!.*potato)(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try without using regex :

> str1 = "potato, orange, potato, plum, pear, etc."
>
> str_index = str1.rfind("potato", 0,len(str1))
>
> print str1[str_index + len("potato")::]
>
> Output ::
>
> , plum, pear, etc.

Comment: thank you. I was looking into a regex as there are many lines so loop needed if going that route... though not sure what the regex parf compared to a loop